# Suppress warning CS8670 in C#

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, nullable-reference-types

Normally, nullability warnings can be suppressed using the null-forgiving operator (!). I just now encountered [CS8670](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings#possible-dereference-of-null) – *Object or collection initializer implicitly dereferences possibly null member* and tried suppressing it using the null-forgiving operator, however that did not work, or more accurately I did not know where to place it. Here is an example:

```cs
class Program {
  public void M() {
    var x = new A
    {
      // Warning is here, when initializing "Items"
      Items = { "Hello", "World" }
    };
  }
}

class A {
  public List<string>? Items { get; init;} = new List<string>();
}
```

The code for `A` is in an external assembly, so I can't modify it. Is it possible to suppress CS8670 using the null-forgiving operator?

Comment: It's because it doesn't make sense to mark `Items` nullable together with `init` and static initialization. It can't ever be `null`.

Comment: A couple of pieces of information you may want to add to your question (since we don't all have the warning codes memorized). 1) the meaning of `CS8670` and 2) the line where the error occurs. It looks like the former is _**CS8670** - Object or collection initializer implicitly dereferences possibly null member._

Comment: @Artur I know it doesn't make sense, but the property is in an external assembly and I can't modify it.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks for the hint, I've added your suggestions.

Comment: @Artur it can be null - `new A {Items = null};`, maybe it is a valid scenario from library author perspective (though I agree - a bit strange).

Comment: @GuruStron you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a one-off scenario, then `#nullable disable`/`#nullable restore` pair, as @Guru mentioned should be good.

Another option is to give up using collection initializer, and instead access `Items` with `!` followed by `!`

```cs
var x = new A();
x.Items!.Add("Hello");
x.Items!.Add("World");

// or
var items = x.Items!;
items.Add("Hello");
items.Add("World");
```

If you find this a common pattern in your code and find these solution inconvenient, you *could* introduce a wrapper around this class, but I think this is *too* much to workaround a nullability warning. So only do this per wise judgement for your specific scenario:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// depending on how you are using "x", then var might work as well.
A x = new AWrapper
{
    Items = { "Hello", "World" }
};


class A
{
    public List<string>? Items { get; init; } = new List<string>();
}

public readonly struct AWrapper
{
    private readonly A _a = new();

    public AWrapper()
    {
    }

    public List<string> Items => _a.Items!;

    public static implicit operator A(AWrapper wrapper) => wrapper._a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`!` is an unary postfix operator and it seems ATM it can't be used in this particular case which is basically translated to series of `Add` calls ([@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwCwG5nJYCcAFAESA8G4CD7ZAlPkoTOgAoBOA9gOZsCGAtnHQBvZOkwBmTNnQBZErRFjx6AG6826AB7oAvOgB2AUwDu6AILLxopCpUB6e+gDqGgwEsDXdO4DO6AAsjNiMAGnQTIIMfDwAXd14AG3cAL09vMgBJWKN+XzIrO0LxbNz/fWF0MgAJI0TEjjJwsmcONkTgMnQAX2LC7oZxXqRhpgslW0l0ABk/WIAeLFQAPgB+dFK8kXQuI1jcGPd97r1DUxm5xbgVhQZuoA=)):

```
A a = new A();
a.Items.Add("Hello");
a.Items.Add("World");
```

You can try using `#nullable disable`:

```cs
var x = new A
{
#nullable disable
    Items = { "Hello", "World" }
#nullable restore
};
```

Or just create a new instance of the list:

```cs
var x = new A
{
    Items = new(){ "Hello", "World" }
};
```

Personally "in general case" I would go with the second option (unless in case of very-very performance-sensitive code) because there is no guarantee that the default initialization will not be removed at some point by the library author.